# React-Table v7 Columns Typscript style type problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

hello i'm stuck and it would be nice if you could tell me
about the problem:

I implemented react-table with these columns

[image]

and as usual rendering them then I wanted to make sure that each column gets dynamic styles and nothing came to my mind how to simply declare the style property inside each column.

As a result, after looking in different places, I got stuck at this moment

[image]

**typescript error sounds like this:**

> TS2322: Type '{ Header: string; accessor: "address"; style: { flex:
> string; minWidth: string; }; }' is not assignable to type
> 'Column'.   Object literal may only specify
> known properties, and 'style' does not exist in type
> 'ColumnInterface & { accessor: "address"; }
> & ColumnInterfaceBasedOnValue<IExtendedColumnInterface, string>'.

I'm new to typescript and can't figure out where I'm making a mistake
I would appreciate any hint or help thanks

Comment: Can you make style an optional prop directly in IColumn?

Comment: @MarioPerez hello yes i tried
but it didn't affect anything.

also i tried to do this -

   style?: {
      flex: string
      minWidth: string
   }
   address: string
   regionalFee: string

and i got this 
 Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'style' does not exist in type 'ColumnInterface<IExtendedColumnInterface>

Comment: Why do you use `ColumnInterface`?

Comment: @ghybs hello, because my OFFICE_COLUMNS array type a Column.
I can't add my own fields as styles: {...}
and I thought if we inherit ColumnInterface and rewrite it, add our style field with the React.CSSProperties type, it will work for me i thought(

Comment: Which version of `react-table` do you use?

Comment: @ghybs  "react-table": "^7.8.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could **extend** the column definition type to suit your needs.
Use the `ColumnDef` type of `tanstack/react-table` and add your style object.

```js
import type { ColumnDef } from '@tanstack/react-table';

// New custom column def type
export type ColumnDefType<T> = ColumnDef<T> & { style?: Record<string, string> };
```

You could use that type when typing your columns. So the style object is available when you create your rows for example. The style object can be extracted from `column.columnDef` and applied where necessary.

```js
import type { ColumnDefType } from '<custom-type-file-location>';

const columns = useMemo<ColumnDefType<YourRowType>[]>(
    () => [
      {
        header: 'Name',
        accessorKey: 'name',
        style: ...
      }
    ]
)
```

This example uses `@tanstack/react-table v8`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options), a column can only have these supported options:

1. **accessor**: String | Function(originalRow, rowIndex) => any
2. **id**: String
3. **columns**: Array
4. **Header**: String | Function | React.Component => JSX
5. **Footer**: String | Function | React.Component => JSX
6. **Cell**: Function | React.Component => JSX
7. **width**: Int
8. **minWidth**: Int
9. **maxWidth**: Int

You can use another way for styling the header. For example, by returning a React Component or ReactNode to the header as follow:

```
{
   id: "header",  // don't forget to set the id
   Header: () => {
     return <div style={{ background: "red" }}>My Header Name</div>;
   }
}
```